# why openstack is getting so popular?

Tags: amazon-web-services, open-source, openstack, openstack-nova, cloudcontrol

can anyone tell me why openstack is getting so popular because there are many open source private computing platforms like opennebula,cloudStack,Eucalyptus...so what is the advantage of using Openstack? and why not others?

Comment: Can you point to any usage data?

Answer (score 1):

OpenStack has lots of contributors and is supported by lots of large IT vendors. It is trying to beat AWS and VMware. It is developing its own set of APIs.

The other open source private cloud platforms have their own strengths. Eucalyptus is the only one with AWS compatibility. You can move workloads back and forth. You can use the same scripting. You can use the same tools. For instance, ChaosMonkey that Netflix developed for their internal use on AWS runs on Eucalyptus as well.